# How to preserve formatting (line breaks) for backend sentence segmentation when copy-pasting text?

Tags: copy-paste

If I copy-paste text which I copied into my mouse from any kind of document (website, word, pdf etc.) into a free field on our widget/website, how can the formatting be preserved until the text arrives at the backend? Our backend is doing sentence segmentation and therefore needs to know the formatting of the text (e.g. line breaks).

Currently, the segmentation is not working very well, so I am thinking about hard rules, but maybe a good editor would be a better solution. Any recommendations?